# How can i prevent my vim plugins being overridden by older ones?

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew, macvim, pathogen

I have installed MacVim via homebrew, and pathogen via downloading the pathogen.vim file to my `~/.vim/autoload` directory. I have got cloned the vim-perl plugin into `~/.vim/bundle` directory.

However, when i open a perl file, it uses the syntax highlighting from the `perl.vim` file included with MacVimand *not* my downloaded plugin. This is the output of `:scriptnames`. Note all the MacVim supplied plugins are there and I think the perl ones listed last overwrite my downloaded plugin:

```
1: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimrc
2: ~/.vimrc
3: ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
4: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftoff.vim
5: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
6: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/synload.vim
7: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
8: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/filetype.vim
9: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript/ftdetect/javascript.vim
10: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-perl/ftdetect/mason-in-html.vim
11: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-perl/ftdetect/perl11.vim
12: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-ruby/ftdetect/ruby.vim
13: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-scala/ftdetect/scala.vim
14: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/menu.vim
15: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/autoload/paste.vim
16: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin.vim
17: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/indent.vim
18: ~/.vim/colors/default.vim
19: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-scala/plugin/scala.vim
20: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
21: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim
22: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/matchparen.vim
23: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
24: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/rrhelper.vim
25: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/spellfile.vim
26: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
27: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/tohtml.vim
28: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
29: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
30: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-scala/after/plugin/help.vim
31: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/gvimrc
32: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-perl/syntax/perl.vim
33: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-perl/syntax/pod.vim
34: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/pod.vim
35: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/perl.vim
36: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-perl/ftplugin/perl.vim
37: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin/perl.vim
38: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-perl/indent/perl.vim
39: /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/indent/perl.vim
```

Here is my `~/.vimrc` file

```
set shell=/bin/sh

call pathogen#infect()

filetype off
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

If I `:so ~/.vim/bundle/vim-perl/syntax/perl.vim` then the file syntax highlights correctly.

How can I prevent the MacVim bundled ones overriding?

Comment: Try moving `filetype off` *above* `call pathogen#infect()`.

Comment: Nope, that made no difference. The files are still there in the same order in `:scriptnames`

Comment: What is `runtimepath` set to?

Comment: `runtimepath=~/.vim,~/.vim/bundle/default,~/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript,~/.vim/bundle/vim-perl,/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73_1/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimfiles,/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73_1/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime,/usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-73_1/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after`

Comment: Looks like my bad :( It was loading the syntax but some was disabled because I had not put it in `after/...`

Answer (score 0):

The inclusion guard (`if exists("b:current_syntax")`) should prevent the default Perl syntax script from having any effect (after your custom one has been sourced).

As a workaround, you could move your own script from `~/.vim/bundle/vim-perl/syntax/perl.vim` to `~/.vim/bundle/vim-perl/after/syntax/perl.vim`, or alternatively create a `~/.vim/after/syntax/perl.vim` script with

```
so ~/.vim/bundle/vim-perl/syntax/perl.vim
```

in it.